# Is the right way to implements OpenMP version of this code?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm beginner in OpenMP technology and parallel programming. So, I would like to know, if the parallel version of this code is ok or I need to improve or change something.

**Serial Code:**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int    N; //size of columns and rows (matrices)
  clock_t start_t, end_t;
  double total_t;
  time_t time_start, time_stop;
  int    tid, nthreads, i, j, k, l;
  double **a, **b, **c, **d, Z;
  double *a_block, *b_block, *c_block, *d_block;

  if(argc<2){
    printf("Usage: mm matrix_size\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  N = atoi(argv[1]);

  a = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* matrix a to be multiplied */
  b = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* matrix b to be multiplied */
  c = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* result matrix c */
  d = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* result matrix d */

  a_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double)); /* Storage for matrices */
  b_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
  c_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
  d_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to a */
    a[i] = a_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to b */
    b[i] = b_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to c */
    c[i] = c_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to d */
    d[i] = d_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) /* last matrix has been initialized */
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      a[i][j]= (i+j) * ((double) rand());
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      b[i][j]= i * j * ((double) rand());
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
      c[i][j]= 0.0;
      d[i][j]= 0.0;
    }
   }

  /* STEP 1: Z is the (integer) sum of ell elements of a anb b */

  start_t = clock(); 
  time_start= time(NULL);
  Z=0.0;

  /* last matrix has been initialized */
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      Z += a[i][j];
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      Z += b[i][j];

  printf("Value of Z: %e\n", Z);

  /* STEP 2: variation of matrix multiplication */

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<N; j++) {    
      for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    for(l=0; l<i+N+N; l++) {
      c[i][j] -= ((Z*k)+l-k)/(l+k);
        }
      }
    }
  }

 /* STEP 3: add elements of matrices d=a+b */

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
      d[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
  }
  end_t = clock();
  time_stop = time(NULL);
  total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC *1000.0;
  printf("Total time taken by CPU: %0.2f seconds. \n", total_t  );
  printf("Task time is about %0.0f seconds for matrix size equals to  %d \n",difftime(time_stop,time_start),N);
  printf ("Done.\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

And, I coded the parallel version in this way :

**Parallel Code:**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int    N; //size of columns and rows (matrices)
  clock_t start_t, end_t;
  double total_t;
  time_t time_start, time_stop;
  int    tid, nthreads, i, j, k, l;
  double **a, **b, **c, **d, Z;
  double *a_block, *b_block, *c_block, *d_block;

  if(argc<2){
    printf("Usage: mm matrix_size\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  N = atoi(argv[1]);

  a = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* matrix a to be multiplied */
  b = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* matrix b to be multiplied */
  c = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* result matrix c */
  d = (double **) malloc(N*sizeof(double *)); /* result matrix d */

  a_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double)); /* Storage for matrices */
  b_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
  c_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
  d_block = (double *) malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to a */
    a[i] = a_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to b */
    b[i] = b_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to c */
    c[i] = c_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++)   /* Initialize pointers to d */
    d[i] = d_block+i*N;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) /* last matrix has been initialized */
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      a[i][j]= (i+j) * ((double) rand());
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      b[i][j]= i * j * ((double) rand());
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
      c[i][j]= 0.0;
      d[i][j]= 0.0;
    }
   }

  /* STEP 1: Z is the (integer) sum of ell elements of a anb b */
  start_t = clock(); 
  time_start= time(NULL);
  Z=0.0;
  /* last matrix has been initialized */

        #pragma omp parallel for  private(i,j) reduction(+:Z) schedule(runtime)
        for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
        {
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                Z += (a[i][j] + b[i][j]) ;
            }

          } 




      printf("Value of Z: %e\n", Z);


      #pragma omp parallel sections 
      {

        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();

        /* STEP 2: variation of matrix multiplication */
        #pragma omp section 
        {
            #pragma parallel for private(i,j,k,l) schedule(runtime)
            for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
                for(j=0; j<N; j++) {    
                    for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
                        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                        for(l=0; l<i+N+N; l++) {
                            c[i][j] -= ((Z*k)+l-k)/(l+k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* STEP 3: add elements of matrices d=a+b */
        #pragma omp section 
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) schedule(runtime)
            for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
                for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
                    d[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
                }
            }

        }
      }


  end_t = clock();
  time_stop = time(NULL);
  total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC *1000.0;
  printf("Threads number is : %d. \n",nthreads);
  printf("Total time taken by CPU: %0.2f seconds. \n", total_t  );
  printf("Task time is about %0.0f seconds for matrix size equals to  %d \n",difftime(time_stop,time_start),N);
  printf ("Done.\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

note: I used runtime schedule policy, because I need to do it customizable by OMP_SCHEDULE  environment variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The initialization in both versions is undefined behavior. *_block is uninitialized, you can't read from it to set the other array's values. If you want them both to be 0-initialized use calloc. If you want them to be some other uniform value use memset. If you want to copy from one array to another use memcpy (but keep in mind that memcpy from an uninitialized source is still UB).

Comment: I understand, however, the initialization wasn't programmed for me. This is an university exercise and the professor gave me the Serial Version as I have posted. The main goal, is need to make a parallel version of it and for this reason, we need to focus on the Matrix Multiplication and the rest of algorithm behavior. Regardless that situation, thanks for your suggestion, maybe I can speak about that with my professor.

Comment: Among other things, you must pay attention to the methods for timing a parallel program, unless you are looking only for the total time spent by all threads.  Did you forget to show your parallel modifications?

Comment: Hi, no the second code (Parallel Code), is my implementation and the Serial Code, is the original code that they gave me, but it is my first time using OpenMP and I have a basic C knowledge, I'm not sure about the implementation that I have coded. 
On the other hand, I don't understand the error about the time measuring. I tried something similar to Stopwatch behavior in Java.